# How to achieve the UI effect which swipe listview with a 'X' from gone to visible and accompany with the item?

Tags: android-listview, android

How to achieve the UI effect which swipe listview with a 'X' from gone to visible and accompany with the item?
I want to achieve a UI effect which when I swipe a listview item,there would be a 'X'follow it.What I use to achieve swipe listview is [EnhancedListView](https://github.com/timroes/EnhancedListView).
What I want to achieve is like this:
At first,the listview will be like this:
[image: First Image]

When I swipe it:[image: Second image]

Then the picture will be:[image: Third picture]

I wonder how to achieve the effect.As the listview I use now,there are two layers of the listview item that I can swipe to let the bottom layer shown.But it can hardly achieve the effect like that.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/steelkiwi/ListView-Swipe-to-Delete  this is probably what you're looking for..